# How to carry over values from one month to +3 months

Tags: google-sheets, offset

I would like to carry over values from one month to +3 months from the given table using formulas in google sheet.

A sheet with sample data and query is below
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pa2HlsG8rDtM6nDe5Ty0JPOYzdvZ2nUu1yGwqW-1tO8/edit#gid=0

The desired result is in 16 and 17 rows.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=makearray(counta(B16:B),counta(C14:N14),lambda(r,c,+ifna(filter(filter(C5:N6,B5:B6=index(B16:B,r)),C4:N4=index(eomonth(edate(C14:N14,-C12),),,c)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look at months at all, it shifts data to right according to `C12` value. Formula in `C16`:

```
=byrow(C5:N6,lambda(x,if($C$12>0,(HSTACK(arrayformula(replace(sequence(1,$C$12,,),1,1,"")),ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(X,1,COLUMNS(x)-$C$12))),X)))
```

Result:

[image]